# Tensorflow - use previously learned weights to initialize new weights of different dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use previously learned weights of dimension `m` to initialize a weight tensor of dimension `n` where `n > m`. I can do it as I've done below.

```
all_weights['w1'] = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n, output_sz], dtype=tf.float32))
all_weights['w1'] = all_weights['w1'][:m,:].assign(initial_weights['w1'])
```

However, I'm having an issue later on when the actual learning happens that I don't come across if I don't use weight sharing. `w1` is initially a tf.Variable and I noticed it changes to a Tensor object after the slicing assignment: `Tensor("strided_slice/_assign:0")`. My issue is I'm getting the error:

```
`LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'strided_slice_2/_assign' (op type: StridedSliceAssign)`.
```

Does this have to do with the type (Tensor vs tf.Variable)? Does it make sense to some how cast the Tensor to a tf.Variable? I tried to do this but then I get an error like:

```
`FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_4
 [[Node: strided_slice/_assign = StridedSliceAssign[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_4"], begin_mask=3, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=2, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_4, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2, strided_slice/_assign/value)]]`
```

I'm relatively new to Tensorflow so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.Variable` is a very different thing from `Tensor`. It does not make sense to "cast" between them.

The easiest solution is to just use the `initial_weights` directly in the `Variable` creation. For example, something like this:

```
import numpy as np
tf.Variable(np.append(initial_weights['w1'],
                      np.zeros((n-m, output_sz)),
                      axis=0),
            dtype=tf.float32)
```